# Android: DatePicker shows wrong day order after min date setting

Tags: android

Basically, we want to let user schedule a day in future from now. Here is code:

```
DatePicker date_picker = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.date_picker);
date_picker.setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis()); 
// other settings
```

First, it shows current day: 04/Aug/2017, but when scrolling month, something strange happens:

[image]

Comment: I found that if I scroll back to min date, it'll happen. So is there a way to reset DatePicker when this disorder happen?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

By this user can select the **minimum date is current date**

```
        DatePicker date_picker = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.date_picker);
        date_picker.setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000);
```